# In meson can you test for presence of a directory in your project?

Tags: build, build-system, meson-build

Using meson build, is it possible to test for the existence of a directory in my project?

For example, I typically put acceptance tests next to my unit tests in a folder structure like this:

```
library/
        header.hp
        src/
            lib.cpp
        tests/
              acceptance_test/
              unit_test/
```

I don't always have acceptance tests, and I'd like to avoid having to have a meson.build file there if it isn't necessary. I'd much rather have a conditional `subdir('acceptance_test')` if the directory `acceptance_test/` exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**
Starting with Meson v0.53.0, you can use the [Filesystem](https://mesonbuild.com/Fs-module.html) module:

```
fs = import('fs')
if fs.is_dir('<dirname>')
  message('directory exists')
endif
```

This is portable, and does not depend on a shell.

Answer (score 5):

Looking through the [reference manual](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/wiki/Reference%20manual), I don't see any direct support for this.

You can use `run_command`, doing something like

```
if run_command('[', '-d', dirname, ']').returncode() == 0
    message('directory exists')
endif
```

but, of course, that has the disadvantage of not working across platforms.

Comment: I didn't think `run_command` will work because the commands are not actually run while generating the configuration, they are run by ninja after the fact.

Comment: I just tried it. It prints 'directory exists' when you run the the meson command, and I didn't have any trouble running subdir within the if condition either.

Comment: @mickb My comment was based on what the wiki & unit test cases said, I appreciate you taking the time to try it out.

Comment: @mickb, I imagine I could call a python script in run_command, and since meson is python3 that's already a dependency.